# Why do some services not show up in my "Services" app in windows server 2019?

Tags: windows, powershell, service, windows-server-2019

In the image below, i have several services running, including some `ovs` services.  I found however that when i try to list these services (i was going to try to find their dependencies through the UI), the "Services" application on Windows doesn't show them.

Why is it that some services only show up in my powershell `Get-Services` output, but **not** in the corresponding "Services" window on windows 2019 ?

Note: I am logged in as an administrator, so I assume that there is no permissions issue here.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking closely, *in windows* you **must** actually launch the **services** application as an administrator in order to see ALL processes that are running., as shown in the image below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLuRl.png).

[image]

Comment: this of course begs the question: How do you stop a starting service ?